# Big Query Pivot multiple columns in 2 columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

How can I transform/pivot in Big Query:

From this:

```
solution                   sentiment     groups                feeling  playing doing 

I am good                  positive    ['good', 'am']            1        0      0
I am playing               positive    ['playing', 'am']         0        1      1
She is running             positive    ['running', 'she]         0        1      0
He is not eating           negative    ['eating']                1        0      1
```

To:

```
solution                   sentiment     groups                    name     value

I am good                  positive    ['good', 'am']              feeling    1
I am good                  positive    ['good', 'am']              playing    0
I am good                  positive    ['good', 'am']              doing      0

I am playing               positive    ['playing', 'am']           feeling    0
I am playing               positive    ['playing', 'am']           playing    1
I am playing               positive    ['playing', 'am']           doing      1

She is running             positive    ['running', 'she]           feeling     0
She is running             positive    ['running', 'she]           playing     1
She is running             positive    ['running', 'she]           doing       1

He is not eating           negative    ['eating']                  feeling     1
He is not eating           negative    ['eating']                  playing     0
He is not eating           negative    ['eating']                  doing       1
```

I tried this way, but I am missing the `name` column...rest is looking fine.

```
SELECT solution, sentiment, groups, value
FROM table
LEFT JOIN UNNEST ([feeling, playing doing] ) AS value
```

I have tried like this to get the `name` column but doesn't work as it is giving wrong results:

```
    SELECT solution, sentiment, groups, value, name
    FROM table, 
    UNNEST (['feeling', 'playing','doing']) AS name
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST ([feeling, playing, doing] ) AS value
```

Might need to `UNNEST` the `name` column in a nice way.

How do I create the `name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`UNPIVOT` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator) for this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (
  solution STRING,
  sentiment STRING,
  `groups` ARRAY<STRING>,
  feeling BOOLEAN,
  playing BOOLEAN,
  doing BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO t
  (solution, sentiment, `groups`, feeling, playing, doing)
VALUES
  ('I am good', 'positive', ['good', 'am'], true, false, false),
  ('I am playing', 'positive', ['playing', 'am'], false, true, true),
  ('She is running', 'positive', ['running', 'she'], false, true, false),
  ('He is not eating', 'negative', ['eating'], true, false, true);

SELECT *
FROM t UNPIVOT(value FOR name IN (feeling, playing, doing));
```

returns

```
solution    sentiment   groups  value   name
He is not eating    negative    [eating]    true    feeling
He is not eating    negative    [eating]    false   playing
He is not eating    negative    [eating]    true    doing
I am good   positive    "[good,am]" true    feeling
I am good   positive    "[good,am]" false   playing
I am good   positive    "[good,am]" false   doing
She is running  positive    "[running,she]" false   feeling
She is running  positive    "[running,she]" true    playing
She is running  positive    "[running,she]" false   doing
I am playing    positive    "[playing,am]"  false   feeling
I am playing    positive    "[playing,am]"  true    playing
I am playing    positive    "[playing,am]"  true    doing
```

---

Your idea of using `UNNEST` can also work, you just need to keep both `name` and `value` in a single array:

```
SELECT solution, sentiment, `groups`, name, value
FROM t, 
UNNEST (
    ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value BOOLEAN>>[('feeling', feeling), ('playing', playing), ('doing', doing)]
) ;
```